# TypeError: undefined is not an object( evaluating 'navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition') in react-native-google-places-autocomplete

Tags: react-native, google-places-autocomplete

I am trying to use **react-native-google-places-autocomplete** for google places and at the sametime I want user **current position** also.

But im getting an error called as

***TypeError: undefined is not an object( evaluating 'navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition')***

i have gone through net searching for solutions everyone saying **navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition** works fine.

but dont know why it is not working for me..

Here is my code

```
componentDidMount() {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  position => {
    const initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
    let region = {
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }
    this.setState({initialPosition:region});
    console.log("lat "+position.coords.latitude+" longi "+position.coords.longitude)
    console.log("initialPosition")
    console.log(this.state.initialPosition)
  },
   error => console.log("Error "+ JSON.stringify(error)),
  {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000},
);
this.watchID = Geolocation.watchPosition(position => {
  const lastPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
  this.setState({lastPosition});
});
```

}

Comment: which version of react-native are you using?

Comment: react-native: 0.61.4

Comment: im just getting coordinates from this when i checked with console.log but pressing "current location label" is giving value as  "current location"  itself...instead of name of current location ...pls..help me out with this issue?

Comment: is there any way to get directly the name of user's location or something else ...which is proper way ...pls help me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

i have been through **@react-native-community/geolocation** and i found solution here. i have done the following steps.
1. install @react-native-community/geolocation via

```
npm install @react-native-community/geolocation --save
```

2. add the following line above the class in GooglePlacesAutocompleteExample.js file in side nodemodules of react-native-google-places-autocomplete

   `navigator.geolocation = require('@react-native-community/geolocation');`

   finish it works..

Comment: working but I am getting Location request timed out

Answer (score 13):

1. `npm install @react-native-community/geolocation --save`
2. `import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';`
3. Instead of `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` use `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition`

Comment: This appears to be what the accepted answer already stated. Duplicate answers should not be posted.

Answer (score 3):

With reference to [react-native documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.58/geolocation#__docusaurus),
starting from react-native 0.58, react-native team suggests to use [@react-native-community/geolocation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation). And the API for geolocation before react-native 0.58 is deprecated.